# How to use"select" and "withColumn" together- Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, select, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two dataframes df1 and df2

I have to join the the two dataframes and create a new one
the join is carried using df1.col1 = df2.col1, inner join
My query here is can I use "select" and "withColumn" statements together?

for example

```
df3 = df1.join(df2,df1.col1 = df2.col1,'inner').select(df1.col4,df2.col4).
      withColumn("col2",(df1.col1+df2.col2))
      withColumn("col3",(df1.col1/df2.col2))
```

How can I achieve this
separately select and withcolumn works.

[Dataframe_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFf9F.png)

Comment: Yes you can use.. Did you see any issues?

Comment: yes, It throws me : AnalysisException: 'Resolved attribute(s) error

Answer (score 2):

You need to select all the required columns in **`.select`** and only those columns will be used in **`.withColumn`**

**`Example:`**

```
df1=spark.createDataFrame([("a","1","4","t"),("b","2","5","v"),("c","3","6","v")],["col1","col2","col3","col4"])
df2=spark.createDataFrame([("a","1","4","ord2"),("b","2","5","ord1"),("c","3","6","ord3")],["col1","col2","col3","col4"])

df1.join(df2,df1.col1 == df2.col1,'inner').select(df1.col1,df2.col2,df1.col3,df1.col2,df2.col4).withColumn("col3",(df1.col3 / df2.col2).cast("double")).withColumn("col2",(df1.col2 + df2.col2).cast("int")).show()

#+----+----+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|col2|col4|
#+----+----+----+----+----+
#|   a|   2| 4.0|   2|ord2|
#|   b|   4| 2.5|   4|ord1|
#|   c|   6| 2.0|   6|ord3|
#+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to rearrange the order of your operations. From all the columns in the dataframe `select` filters that list. If you intent to use `withColumn` make sure the columns are available (selected). As a rule of thumb, leave `select`  statements at the end of your transformations.

```
    # make sure to use the keyword` attributes so you don't get confused
    df3 = df1.join(df2, on='col1',how='inner') \
          .withColumn("col2",(df1.col2+df2.col2)) \
          .withColumn("col3",(df2.col3/df1.col2)) \
          .select('col1', 'col2', 'col3', df2.col4)
```

To see what is happening in each of the transformations add `.show()` statement and it will all be much clearer step by step.